# Merge multiple paths in CanvasRenderingContext2D to fill and stroke as a set

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-canvas

I am currently drawing a set of overlapping shapes using paths in a CanvasRenderingContext2D. This works well however I would now like to unite all these paths so that when I fill using a semi-transparent color the overlapping is not shown. Also I would like to stroke the contour of the united shapes. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: You're using the Phaser JS framework, correct? If so the correct trash is actually `phaser-framework`. Can you also include any relevant code that you have already? It makes it easier for someone to help.

Comment: TBH: i do use Phaser but this is not a Phaser question so i just removed the Phaser tag altogether...

Comment: I noticed this question while writing [Transparency groups in CanvasRenderingContext2D](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36578651/1468366). To some users visiting this post, [clipper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) might be a useful tool to merge paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Mark however I think I have found a better way to do this.

I draw my shapes on a blank bitmapdata and then use it as an alpha mask...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want overlapping semi-transparent pixels to interact, you can change the semi-transparent pixels (RGBA format) into equivelant opaque pixels (RGB format).

```
function RGBAtoRGB(r, g, b, a, backgroundR,backgroundG,backgroundB){
    var r3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * backgroundR) + (a * r))
    var g3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * backgroundG) + (a * g))
    var b3 = Math.round(((1 - a) * backgroundB) + (a * b))
    return "rgb("+r3+","+g3+","+b3+")";
}
```

You must draw each sub-shape with a separate `beginPath`. This is necessary because you only get one styling (styling==fillStyle) per beginpath.

Depending on your design requirements, you might have to rearrange the drawing order of your sub-shapes so the desired opaque shapes are on top.