# Transparency groups in CanvasRenderingContext2D

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas, 2d, transparency, alphablending

Is there a way to combine multiple draw operations to a 2d canvas rendering context in such a way that they their *combined* result is composed onto the previous content of the canvas, as opposed to each drawing operation being composed by itself?

One application: I'd like to draw a translucent line with an arrow head, and I'd like to avoid increased opacity in those areas where the line and the arrow head overlap.

Many other rendering models support such features. SVG has a [group opacity](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/masking.html#ObjectAndGroupOpacityProperties) setting, described in section 14.5. The [PDF reference](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf) describes “Transparency Groups” in section 7.3. In many graphics applications a user can build layers and then compose them as a whole.

I guess I could set up a second invisible canvas to be used as an off-screen image, render my content to that and then use [`globalAlpha`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha) to compose the result onto the main canvas with the desired translucency. But I hope that there is some more elegant solution, even if I couldn't find it in the docs so far.

[Merge multiple paths in CanvasRenderingContext2D to fill and stroke as a set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35988889/1468366) apparently has a similar goal in mind. But the focus there appears to be how to perform boolean operations on paths, probably the way [clipper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) does it. So for this post here, I'm not interested in manipulating the paths up front; I want to be able to draw each stroke as I usually would.

Comment: There is no way around using an intermediate canvas, but one could consider Path2D usage to store various shapes. These can be combined in any combination and stroked/filled at once (path1.addPath(path2); ctx.fill(path1) etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's currently not possible without using an intermediate canvas.

*Unless* all of your draw operations in question can be combined into a single path, thereby using a single call to `stroke()` and `fill()`. I assume that's not the case here, but people searching later may be looking for that information.

```
// two rectangles composed into a single draw operation:
ctx.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
ctx.rect(5, 5, 10, 10);
ctx.fill();

// With transparency, the above produces a different result from:
ctx.rect(0, 0, 10, 10);
ctx.fill();
ctx.rect(5, 5, 10, 10);
ctx.fill();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because I'm used to the idea of layers, I do believe the off-sreen canvas is still the most elegant way to do it.

But note that in the **exceptional*** case of an empty canvas, you can also achieve it on a single canvas element, thanks to the [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property.

The idea is to first draw your group of overlapping paths opaque, then use the gCO <s>`"destination-in"` and draw a rectangle covering the whole area of the group with the wanted color</s><sub>(see comments and down of post edit for a better way of doing it, still with gCO)</sub> :

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

// first draw your overlapping paths opaque
ctx.lineWidth = 10;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(40, 40, 35, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(60, 60, 35, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.stroke();
// then set the fill color to the one you want
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0,.5)';
// set the gCo so we only draw on the existing pixels
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
// draw a large rect
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
```

```css
p{position: absolute;z-index:-1}
body{background-color: ivory;}
```

```html
<p>Is this transparent ?</p>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

<sup>*</sup>  Actually, the only one case I can think of where it could be the case, would be for an off-screen canvas ;-)

### Edit

As noted by [@K3N](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1693593/k3n), it can even be [simplified](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/8doyu98x/) and [improved](https://jsfiddle.net/8doyu98x/1/) by using the `"copy"` composite operation.

Comment: In that case you could simply draw solid, set comp mode to copy and draw the canvas back on itself with reduced alpha: https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/8doyu98x/ It will in either case not mix well with existing content. (you also probably meant to use rgb( and not rgba( on the first usage of it)

Comment: @K3N you're absolutely right about copy, I'm never sure which gCO were fully supported by older browsers so I try to keep with the `destination-xxx` and `source-xxx` ones, but `copy` seems to be supported in IE9 too ;-) Good to know. And for the `rgba`what I meant was to delete it entirely since with these operations, the color at this stage doesn't matter, just the opacity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Right now, combining multiple subpaths into a single path to be stroked in one operation is the simpler solution, so I'm accepting Simon's answer. But I cen see how yours could handle situations that one can not, and eventually I might end up doing a mixture of both. So thanks you very much for the effort you put into this!